# How can you get data from nested interface variable by a subscription in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to subscribe data from a json-placeholder with the interface I have given below. I need to name every value from arrays of address and company. After achieving this, I just need to know how I can get these values.

### ** Interface **

```
export interface Users{
    id?:number,
    name:string,
    username:string,
    email:string,
    phone:string,
    website:string,
    address:Address[],
    company:Company[]
}

export interface Company{
    bs:string,
    catchPhrase:string,
    name:string
}

export interface Geo{
    lat:string,
    lng:string
}

export interface Address{
    city:string,
    geo?:Geo[],
    street:string,
    suite:string,
    zipcode:string
}
```

### ** Subscription **

```
this.users.GetUsers().subscribe(
      (users) =>{
      for(let u of users){
        console.log(`
          Name: ${u.name} \n
          Username: ${u.username} \n
          Email: ${u.email} \n
          Phone: ${u.phone} \n
          Website: ${u.website} \n
          Address: ${u.address} \n 
          Company: ${u.company} \n
        `)
      }
    },
    (err) =>{ console.error(err) }
    )
```

### ** Service **

```
GetUsers(): Observable<Users[]>{
    return this.http.get<Users[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
```

### ** Response **

```
Name: Clementina DuBuque 

          Username: Moriah.Stanton 

          Email: Rey.Padberg@karina.biz 

          Phone: 024-648-3804 

          Website: ambrose.net 

          Address: [object Object] 
 
          Company: [object Object]
```

Comment: Where's the actual problem?

Comment: I need to return values. 
Address: ${JSON.stringify(u.address)} 
I tried this but there are nested values.
After knowing how to get these data I will show it to the html

Comment: @student1993: Please see the attached post for possible methods to print objects as-is in `console.log()`. In general, [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) print a `.toString()` version of the object which would be `[object Object]`. In short, try to use `JSON.stringify(u.address)` and `JSON.stringify(u.company)`.

Comment: I understand but I need the nested json. As toString() will give a json format as a string

Comment: So access the nested properties and construct a string from them?